# pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2145107924), None)

Tags: python, subprocess, win32com

I was working on windows new released patches automatically downloading and installing once i run the python scripts, i am fetching available patches and installed patches, once code come in the part of  downloading and installing patches its throwing error something like
"", line 2, in Search
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2145107924), None)"

could please tell me, where i did mistake?

```
import subprocess
import win32com.client
import win32con
import win32api
import pywintypes
import re


wua = win32com.client.Dispatch("Microsoft.Update.Session")


print("installed Windows or Drivers' Updates...")
update_seeker = wua.CreateUpdateSearcher()
search_not_available = update_seeker.Search("IsInstalled=1 and Type='Software'")
updates = win32com.client.Dispatch("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

for update_available in search_not_available.Updates:
    print("Name: {}".format(update_available))
    updates.Add(update_available)



print("Find updates available")
update_seeker = wua.CreateUpdateSearcher()
search_available = update_seeker.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")
updates = win32com.client.Dispatch("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")

if search_available.Updates.Count !=0:
    for update_available in search_available.Updates:
        print("Name: {}".format(update_available))
        updates.Add(update_available)
else:
    print("You're up to date...")





print("Download available updates")
downloader = wua.CreateUpdateDownloader()
downloader.Updates = updates
if updates.Count != 0:
    downloader.Download()
else:
    print('New Updates not Available for Dowmload')


updatesToInstall = win32com.client.Dispatch("Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl")
rebootMayBeRequired = False
for update in search_available.Updates:
    if update.IsDownloaded == True:
        updatesToInstall.Add(update)
    if update.InstallationBehavior.RebootBehavior > 0:
        rebootMayBeRequired = True


print("Install updates")
installer = wua.CreateUpdateInstaller()
installer.Updates = updatesToInstall
if updatesToInstall.Count != 0:
    result = installer.Install()
    print("ResultCode: {}".format(result.ResultCode))
    for idx, update in enumerate(updatesToInstall.Updates):
        print("{}: {}".format(update.Title, result.GetUpdateResult[i].ResultCode))

else:
    print('New Patches not abaible for install..')
```

Comment: Perhaps step through in the debugger to identify the exact line that is failing, and give us the full error text?